# Active admin "AND" filter with check boxes

Tags: filter, activeadmin, meta-search

I have simple active admin filter in my `Parent` resource:

```
filter :child_id, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { Child.all }
filter :child_id_not, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => proc { Child.all }
```

I want to get all Parent resources that are or not associated with Child resource (has_and_belongs_to_many). Works not bad, but when I select for example two childs in first filter active admin returns all Parent resources that are associated with first one OR the second one. I need "AND" operator for both (:child_id and :child_id_not).

Any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to roll out your own scopes. ActiveAdmin uses meta_search for its filters (https://github.com/ernie/meta_search).

In your admin file:

```
filter :child_id_all,
  :as => :check_boxes,
  :collection => proc { Child.all }

filter :child_id_all_not,
  :as => :check_boxes,
  :collection => proc { Child.all }
```

In your parent model:

```
scope :child_id_all_in, -> ids {
  ids.reduce(scoped) do |scope, id|
    subquery = Parent.select('`parents`.`id`').
      joins(:childs).
      where('`childs`.`id` = ?', id)
    scope.where("`parents`.`id` IN (#{subquery.to_sql})")
  end
}
scope :child_id_all_not_in, -> ids {
  ids.reduce(scoped) do |scope, id|
    subquery = Parent.select('`parents`.`id`').
      joins(:childs).
      where('`childs`.`id` = ?', id)
    scope.where("`parents`.`id` NOT IN (#{subquery.to_sql})")
  end
}
search_methods :child_id_all_in
search_methods :child_id_all_not_in
```